# An extreme point of a polyhedron is a vertex.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry

I have run into a problem relative to linear progamming. This problem is about extreme point and vetices of a polyheron. The question is that an extreme point and a vertex of a polyhedron is equivalent. I guess the answer is yes and I have proved a vertex is an extreme point. However, I have difficulty in proving an extreme point is a vertex.

I know one way to prove is using basic feasible solutions but my lecturer asked to prove not using that convention.

The definition of an extreme point of a polyheron is

> Let $P$ be a polyhedron. A vector $x \in P$ is an extreme point of $P$ if we cannot find two vectors $y, z \in P$, both different from $x$, and a scalar $\lambda \in [0,1]$, such that $x=\lambda y +(1-\lambda) z$.

For a vertex, this following definition is know

> Let $P$ be a polyhedron. A vector $x \in P$ is a vertex of $P$ of there exists some $c$ such that $c'x < c'y$ for all $y$ satisfying $y \in P$ and $y \neq x$.

Both two definitions come from the book "Introduction to Linear Optimization" by Dimistris Bertsimas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For these kinds of problems, the geometry should guide you. There is an answer below, but first consider the following hint:

> The definition of a vertex says that we can find a $c$ so that the entire polytope is in the strict half space defined by $c$, and $x$ alone is in the hyperplane defined by $c$. So if $x$ is not a vertex, we can find a $c$ and $y,z \in P$ so that $y$ and $z$ not $x$ are on parallel hyperplanes normal to $c$, with $x$ sandwiched between them. Draw a picture. Does this give you information about $x$ with respect to $y$ and $z$?

Below is a solution.

---

Suppose that $x$ is not a vertex. Then there is no such $c$; in particular, there are $x \neq y,z  \in P$ and $0 \neq c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $c^Tx < c^Ty$ and $c^Tx \geqslant c^Tz$.  I claim this implies that $x \in \text{conv}(y,z)$.

Notice that $c^Tx$ is in $[c^Ty, c^Tz] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then there is some $\lambda \geqslant 0$ so that:

$$\lambda c^Ty + (1-\lambda)c^Tz = c^Tx$$

By multilinearity of the dot product (alternatively, properties of matrix multiplication):

\begin{align*}
\lambda c^Ty + (1-\lambda)c^Tz = c^Tx &\Longrightarrow  c^T(\lambda y) + c^T ((1-\lambda)z) = c^T x\\
&\Longrightarrow c^T(\lambda y + (1-\lambda)z) = c^T x
\end{align*}

Since $c \neq 0$, this implies $\lambda y + (1-\lambda)z = x$ for $y,z\neq x$ in $P$, so $x$ is not an extreme point.

Hence if $x$ is an extreme point, $x$ is a vertex.

Comment: I haven't understood why there is no such c, there are y, z so that...

Comment: $x$ is not a vertex that means for all $c \neq 0$, there is $y \in P$, $y \neq x$ such that $c^Tx \ge c^T y$.

Comment: If there exists c as you say, x is not an vertex, too.

Comment: The negation of $x$ a vertex tells me that there's no $c$ that works for *every* $y$. Thus if I pick $y,z \neq x$ in the polytope, I get a $c$ that works for $y$, but not for $z$. I then use this to get my result. You might be interested in examining *why* I can guarantee that there is a $y$ for which $c$ bounds correctly.

Comment: That's what I wonder. Why can you guarantee there is a $y$ for which $c$ bound?

Comment: I like to think of this geometrically-- if there were no $y$, then we would be "looking at" the reverse half space of a vertex. In arithmetical terms: if there was no $y$, then for all $y \neq x$, it must be that $c^Tx > c^Ty$. Then $-c^Tx < -c^Ty$ (this is flipping the half-space we're "looking at") for all $y \neq x$, which is the vertex condition. So if $x$ is not a vertex, there has to be a $y$ for which $c$ bounds, and a $z$ for which it bounds in the opposite direction.

Comment: But when $x \neq y$ and $c \neq 0$, we can't conclude that $c^T x > c^T y$. For example, $c=(1,1)$, $x=(0,1), y=(-1,2)$ then $c^T x = c^T y$.

Comment: My claim is that we can find a $c$, not that it holds for all $c$'s. That said, you are right that we can't always sharpen a bound; there was a mistake in my proof of that kind that I have fixed.

Comment: How does $c^T(\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z)=c^Tx$ imply $\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z=x$?